# Book on Riemannian Manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, book-recommendation

I am writing my bachelor's thesis which is in part about Riemannian Manifolds but not extensively and I am using the book Introduction to Smooth Manifolds by Lee. However, I find the Riemannian Manifold part requires a lot of information on covectors, tensors, etc. So I want to ask if there is any other book that introduces Riemannian manifold in an intuitive manner and self-contained in a way that does not require tensors, covectors, etc.

Comment: Check do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry."

Comment: For a non-technical introduction, Frank Morgan's [Riemannian Geometry: A Beginners Guide](https://www.amazon.com/Riemannian-Geometry-Beginners-Guide-Second/dp/1568810733) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO [Lee](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5) is a fine book. There exist plenty of books, what's your budget? Take a look at [Lang](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-0541-8) and [Lang](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4182-9) or [Prasolov](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-92249-8). I sometimes prefer other schools for *doing things*, in this case Lang = FR and Parsolov = RU. [Sharpe](https://link.springer.com/book/9780387947327) is on my wishlist.

I have some books on Tensors and VA, but because I wasn't satisfied ended up buying DG books as mentioned above.

Hope this helps a bit.